# Activity to Activity Communication

Tags: android, android-activity, communication, android-intent

```
Activity myActivity  = AssumeSomeActivityExists();
    Intent openActivity = new Intent();
    openActivity.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    openActivity.setClass(myActivity,B.class);
    myActivity.startActivity(openActivity);
```

When we do something like above how to make `B` instance know that it is been called and created by Activity `myActivity`?

Answer (score 2):

Use extras with your Intent.

Smth like `openActivity.putExtra("calledFromA", true)`

Then in B:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    boolean isCalledFromA = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("calledFromA", false);
}
```