# Activity to Activity communication in MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, software-design

We have been sharing data between activities using extras like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046612/activity-to-activity-communication). Now with MVVM, data is available in viewmodel and next activity to be launched is bound to another viewmodel.

Activity1 -> ViewModel1

Activity2 -> ViewModel2

I need to send data from ViewModel1 to ViewModel2 while starting Activity2

What is the right way to share data between activities in MVVM architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to pass data with Parcelable.
Except that, in term of dependency inversion, another approach is to share the same instance of some kind of data structure between `Activity1` and `Activity2`.

Assume that you have a `User` class, In `SignInActivity` you fill this class and in `ProfileActivity` you get/update data from that class.

So, using a DI framework (like Dagger), you can create a class which has an application lifecycle:

```
class UserStore/Repository/OrWhatEver {
    val user : LiveData<User> 

    fun update(user: User) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

To achieve more reactive style, you can use `LiveData`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go ahead with shared data store approach :)